# How to rotate a image so that it seems like it's floating in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have added an image in XAML and want to continuously rotate it randomly so that it seems like it's floating.
Here is the code that I have already tried.

**XAML**

```
<Image Source="Assets\balloon-red.png"
           x:Name="redBaloon"
           Width="300"
           Stretch="Uniform"
           Height="Auto"
           Margin="490,124,490,-124" />
```

**C#**

```
public MainPage()  
{
    this.InitializeComponent();  
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;  
    Random randRotate = new Random();  
    RotateTransform imageRotate = new RotateTransform();  
    redBaloon.RenderTransform = imageRotate;  
    imageRotate.Angle = randRotate.Next(-5,5);  
}
```

It rotates just one time. But I want it to rotate continuously. How can I do that? I think I have to write the code outside the main class, but I don't know the proper way. Please help me out.

Comment: try `DoubleAnimation` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its a kind of answer I was searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeat the rotation continuously you can use DispatcherTimer.

```
public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        StartTimers();
    }

    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    public void StartTimers() {
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    // callback runs on UI thread
    void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e) {
        // execute repeating task here
        Random randRotate = new Random();
        RotateTransform imageRotate = new RotateTransform();
        redBaloon.RenderTransform = imageRotate;
        imageRotate.Angle = randRotate.Next(-5, 5);
    }
```

The above code repeats the operation defined inside the Tick.

For more details on this look here [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer)